# Hw can I use arrange in dplyr to order groups?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to group data and then arrange the table so that groups with the highest values are shown first. E.g. in mtcars dataset, I would like to group the cars by number of cylinders and then arrange the table so that the groups with the highest mean `mpg` are shown first

```
mtcars %>% group_by (cyl)  %>% arrange (desc(mean (mpg)))
```

this produces an error:

```
Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 32
```

the reason I am asking is that filter() when applied after group_by() is applied to the whole group, not individual rows.

Comment: @AllanCameron OP wants to arrange by the mean `mpg` for each `cyl` grouping, not by `cyl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this? First, group by `cyl`, then fill a new column with `mean(mpg)`, which you can then arrange by however you want, and finally remove the temporary `mean(mpg)` column.

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
  arrange(desc(mean_mpg)) %>%
  select(-mean_mpg)

#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  22.8     4 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  2  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  3  22.8     4 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#>  4  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1
#>  5  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2
#>  6  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     4     1
#>  7  21.5     4 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1
#>  8  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1
#>  9  26       4 120.     91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2
#> 10  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1     1     5     2
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

Comment: yes, this is what I thought, but unfortunately this means that filter and arrange have inconsistent behviors: whereby filter does operate on group levels, arrange does not.

Comment: I think a better way to put it is that `arrange` does not allow for summary functions. They both work within groups.

Answer (score 5):

A good way to do this is to turn the grouping variable into a `factor` and use `reorder` (or `forcats::fct_reorder`) to control the order of the levels. Then you can `arrange` by that column. (The grouping is implicit in the `reorder` functions.)

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    cyl = reorder(factor(cyl), -mpg) 
    # stats::reorder, built-in, uses mean by default
    # use -mpg to make it descending
  ) %>%
  arrange(cyl)

# alternately
library(forcats)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    cyl = fct_reorder(factor(cyl), mpg, .fun = mean, .desc = TRUE)
    # forcats::fct_reorder, uses median by default,
    # takes a .desc argument to make it descending
  ) %>%
  arrange(cyl)
```

Changing the data like this is nice because the order you specify will be remembered and used by other functions (like ordering bars or facets in a `ggplot`).