# Arrange by Column Before Grouping by Other Columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to arrange a data frame by one column, and then group it by two other columns.

A sample code and my attempt is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(person = c("p1", "p2", "p4", "p3","p2", "p3", "p1", "p4"),
                 data1 = c("a","a","b","b","b","a","b","a"),
                 data2 = c(8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))


df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(person, data1) %>%
  arrange(desc(data2),  person, data1)


person data1 data2
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 p1     a         8
2 p2     a         7
3 p4     b         6
4 p3     b         5
5 p2     b         4
6 p3     a         3
7 p1     b         2
8 p4     a         1
```

It is supposed to descend (highest to lowest) of `data2`, but group it by `person` & `data` so that the corresponding `person` row follows underneath the higher row.

The desired result looks like this:

```
    person data1 data2
1     p1     a     8
2     p1     b     2
3     p2     a     7
4     p2     b     4
5     p4     b     6
6     p4     a     1
7     p3     b     5
8     p3     a     3
```

Comment: Give this link a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503447/hw-can-i-use-arange-in-dplyr-to-order-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the max data2 by person, and then arrange by that max

```
df %>% 
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(m=max(data2)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(m), person, desc(data2)) %>%
  select(-m)
```

Output:

```
  person data1 data2
1     p1     a     8
2     p1     b     2
3     p2     a     7
4     p2     b     4
5     p4     b     6
6     p4     a     1
7     p3     b     5
8     p3     a     3
```

equivalently:

```
df%>% 
  inner_join(
    df %>% group_by(person) %>%
      summarize(m=max(data2)),
    by="person"
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(m), person, desc(data2)) %>% 
  select(-m)
```

Comment: yep, that's a good point.. I've added that - thnks

Comment: perhaps poor formatting on my part.  That is just the `by=` argument in the `inner_join()` call. (i.e. its not in the `summarize`)..  Its not strictly needed (the inner join will be `by="person"` even if I don't indicate, but I like to be explicit in what I'm joining on.

Comment: yep, that is my initial solution, as you can see.  I added the second, because surprisingly, I found it slightly faster, which surprised me, but I didn't do any real benchmarking..